# GeoNodes Fur and Rigs

Tags: rigging, particles, geometry-nodes, hair

[image]

Hi everyone! I am having fun playing around with the GeoNodes fur but as I was working on a little character I started having a lot of questions about what's the process meant to look like. I first modelled my character (quite low poly but with subdivisions on top), then I uv-unwrapped it. At this point I added the fur from Curve>fur, then used the settings on the geonodes to customize my fur and I added some additional node from the assets library.

I met two main problems:

1. Every now and then I would have to move some vertexes of my model around, and every time that would mess up with my fur. Why is this happening? I would understand that would happen if I add geometry, but this is not the case.
2. I added a rig to move my character. The fur followed the rig as expected, though with a lot of glitches, little hair missing all of a sudden or clipping inside the mesh, or also if I was to stretch the mesh too much the fur would not follow and disappear.

As I want to create more characters with this style and explore the hair system more (no animations for now, mainly characters in poses), what's the best workflow to have in general? What's pro's/con's of geohair vs particle hair in this kind of workflow?

Here is my project file if you want to have a look [cat-kimono.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q_BH5Sga-7HQvNx8qa7VJdcR-jAqeWFI/view?usp=sharing)